# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, express

When I try send an array of data to the frontend, it works fine, but when I try to send a sample text to the frontend from the server, getting the error `Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0`. I am getting this error on `console.log(data)`.

```js
fetch("/something", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
  }).then(function (data) {
    // This is the JSON from our response
    console.log(data);
 
  });
```

```js
router.post('/something', () => {
  console.log(req.body);
    res.send('This is sample');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `res.send()` automatically sets the Content-Type response header as well based on the argument passed to the send() method. In your case, `send()` is not detecting a json object as an argument. So, the content type is not json in the response header.

You could use `res.json()` method to send the string as json.

```
router.post('/something', () => {
  console.log(req.body);
    res.json('This is sample');
});
```

Or, pass a javascript object to `res.send()` and it would automatically convert it into json.

```
router.post('/something', () => {
  console.log(req.body);
    res.send({data: 'This is sample'});
});
```

Note: `res.json()` uses `res.send()` under the hood. Read this [article](https://medium.com/gist-for-js/use-of-res-json-vs-res-send-vs-res-end-in-express-b50688c0cddf#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20actual%20difference,res.) to understand the difference between the two methods.